# Can the mobile interstitial be controlled via the Soundcloud widget api?

Tags: soundcloud

We use private Soundcloud files on a client's website. We noticed recently that the mobile view contains an interstitial with two buttons: "Play on SoundCloud" and "Listen in browser". We would like to control that mobile interstitial mainly because the "Play on SoundCloud" button reveals the private URL, which we really don't want to reveal. Can this be done?

Comment: We also have a client complaining about the change. I've searched far and wide but cannot find any references to this recent change. It seems like the message comes from the HTML5 player, but I can't find any information that the player has been updated.

Comment: WebMinder The whole point of private files is to keep the URL masked or hidden from plain view. This recent update at the player level on mobile devices unveils the private URL for the whole world to see. What's more @SoundCloud is not very responsive regarding the issue. Let me know if they get back to you with a solution.

Comment: I actually found the official response on the [Soundcloud forums](https://www.soundcloudcommunity.com/soundcloud/topics/-play-in-soundcloud-or-listen-in-browser-displayed-on-mobile-devices?utm_source=notification&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=new_comment&utm_content=topic_link). Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be any solution in sight yet.

Comment: Thanks @WebMinder. Apparently only SoundCloud can resolve this one for us. Hopefully they do something in a timely manner.